# SUM CASE WHEN CLAUSE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, pivot, case, sum

I have the below Query and I want the Ageing profile to show as a new column 
my ageing profile is 0-30,  31-60, 61-90, 91-120, 121-180, 181-365, 365+

I basically want the results to appear lie this with the Net due appearing in the appropriate ageing bracket.

```
BU   0-30   31-60   61-90   91-120   121-180   181-365   365+
--------------------------------------------------------------
A    
B
C
```

Query:

```
select
 BU,
 Ageing,
 sum(NetDue) as Netdue
 from [dbo].[vw_FACT_CONSOL_CREDITORS]
 where date = @date
 Group by BU, Ageing
Order by BU ;
```

I am new to SQL and just trying to learn so apologise as this is basic stuff
Thanks

Comment: Does the "Ageing" field already exist in your view, and you're just trying to display it in columns like that? Or do you only have a date field, and you need to both properly group the data, and display in the correct column?

Comment: This should really be asked over in Stack Overflow instead of in the DBA section. However, you should look into PIVOT queries for a solution to your problem here.

Comment: @LaughingVergil "Advanced queries" are on-topic for dba.SE. https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic  I think range groupings and pivot columns are definitely not beginner SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the Ageing values match the names of the columns in your expected output, then this should work:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  BU, Ageing, NetDue
    FROM    [dbo].[vw_FACT_CONSOL_CREDITORS]
    WHERE   Date = @date
) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM(NetDue)
    FOR Ageing IN ([0-30], [31-60], [61-90], [91-120], [121-180], [181-365], [365+])
) piv
```

If they are not, then you will need to add some logic to the interior select statement to convert Ageing from whatever it is into those string values (e.g. '0-30', '365+').

As an example to check this, I did the following:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
    BU INT,
    NetDue SMALLMONEY,
    Ageing VARCHAR(10),
    Date DATE
)

INSERT x
VALUES 
  (1, 100, '31-60', '2017-04-01'),
  (2, 25.47, '31-60', '2017-04-01'),
  (1, 90.17, '31-60', '2017-05-01'),
  (1, 16.42, '181-365', '2017-04-01'),
  (2, 99.99, '365+', '2017-04-01')

SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  BU, Ageing, NetDue
    FROM    x
    WHERE   Date = '2017-04-01'
) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM(NetDue)
    FOR Ageing IN ([0-30], [31-60], [61-90], [91-120], [121-180], [181-365], [365+])
) piv
```

which produced the output:

```
BU  0-30    31-60   61-90   91-120  121-180 181-365 365+
1   NULL    100.00  NULL    NULL    NULL    16.42   NULL
2   NULL    25.47   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    99.99
```

All the information (and more) for determining this logic can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server).